# R: overridden == and %in%

Tags: r, r-s4

I wrote an s4 class and overrode the "=="-operator with

```
setMethod("==",
      signature=c(e1="CAttribute", e2="CAttribute"),
      definition=function(e1, e2)
  {
    return(getName(e1) == getName(e2))
  }
)
```

If I now want to test if an instance of CAttribute is in a list of CAttributes,

```
a1 <- new("CAttribute", name="a1")
l <- list(new("CAttribute", name="a1"), new("CAttribute", name="a2"))
a1 %in% l
```

I get the following error

```
Error in match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) : 
  'match' requires vector arguments
```

What do I do wrong, how can I test a list of s4 objects for the occurence of a specific object respective to a certain "=="-operator?

Comment: You did not show us how you overrid %in% operator

Comment: I didn't override it. So that is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not override `%in%`, it will use the current implementation of `%in%` that you can find in the [help](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/function.html):

```
"%in%" <- function(x, table) match(x, table, nomatch = 0) > 0
```

The `match` function does not expect a object of class `CAttribute` and this explains your error.

Answer (score 2):

To be a little more explicit, as @Pop points out the relevant function requires implementation. In this case it would seem that `match` is the relevant function. `match` needs to be made a generic, restricting dispatch to relevant arguments

```
setGeneric("match", signature=c("x", "table"))
```

and then implemented

```
setMethod("match",  c(x="CAttribute", table="CAttribute"),
    function(x, table, nomatch = NA_integer_, incomparables = NULL)
{
    match(getName(x), getName(table), nomatch=nomatch,
          incomparables=incomparables)
})
```

I think this would normally be enough, functions that used `match` (like `%in%`) would now work. But for whatever reason, it does appear necessary to promote `%in%` to a generic

```
setGeneric("%in%")
```

and to implement that

```
setMethod("%in%", c("CAttribute", "CAttribute"),
    function(x, table)
{
    match(x, table, nomatch=0L) > 0L
})
```

For what it's worth, R has 'group generics' so rather than implementing just the `==` operator it would be appropriate to implement, e.g., `?Compare`

```
setMethod("Compare", c(e1="CAttribute", e2="CAttribute"),
     definition=function(e1, e2)
{
    callGeneric(getName(e1), getName(e2))
})
```

which says for all the comparison operators, including `==`, use `getName()` for the comparison.

With a basic class definition

```
CAttribute <- setClass("CAttribute", representation(name="character"))

getName <- function(x) x@name
```

We have

```
CAttribute(name="foo") %in% CAttribute(name=c("foo", "bar"))
## [1] TRUE

CAttribute(name="foo") == CAttribute(name=c("foo", "bar"))
## [1]  TRUE FALSE
```

Notice that the *class* contains a vector, allowing vectorized operations that make R reasonably performant; defining a scalar class and creating a list of them, as in the original question, is likely to be very inefficient.

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(f0=CAttribute(name=rep("A", 1000)),
               f1=replicate(1000, CAttribute(name="A")),
               times=5)
## Unit: microseconds
##  expr       min         lq     median         uq        max neval
##    f0    298.82    306.435    309.681    311.891    334.687     5
##    f1 264214.85 277728.310 286446.876 300839.340 301080.928     5
```

If one were using a list-of-scalars, then it would be necessary to implement, e.g., "match,CAttribute,list-method".